# Autolayout with UIScrollView containing dynamic TableView height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a little problem, I work with Xcode 6 and now as we could see Apple advised to use Autolayout in our apps... And now that's compulsory.

So, I have that problem: I want to layout the ScrollView and the TableView but, I don't know how to do because I'm not an expert of autolayout...
The TableViewCells are dynamics, and appears by a specific action (for example: when a button is tapped) and the ScrollView's resizing automatically and that's the same for TableView's height.

As I said, I want the TableView's height and the ScrollView's height to change automatically and to adapt autolayout with this... But I don't have any idea yet...

Is anyone able to help me ? Please, if you have an idea tell me to hope to solve the problem !

Thank you in advance, and have a nice day ! (sorry I really wanted to post images but I can't currently because of reputation....................)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always put something with blue lines, so I can use AL's suggest constraints at the third button on the bottom right, or use option + shift +command + '=' key to reset suggested constraints.By the way, Watching Stanford ios7 lecture 9 on itunes U is a good way learning autolayout.

Comment: Oh gosh, I didn't think about it ! Thank you that's more simple in this case ^^